# HackerRank Equal with Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, dynamic-programming

For studying Scala, I wrote some code to solve the [Equal problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal/problem). But I am stuck on test case #15 due to timeout.

> Christy is interning at HackerRank. One day she has to distribute some
>   chocolates to her colleagues. She is biased towards her friends and
>   may have distributed the chocolates unequally. One of the program
>   managers gets to know this and orders Christy to make sure everyone
>   gets equal number of chocolates.
>
> But to make things difficult for the intern, she is ordered to
>   equalize the number of chocolates for every colleague in the following
>   manner,
>
> For every operation, she can choose one of her colleagues and can do
>   one of the three things.
>
> 1. She can give one chocolate to every colleague other than chosen one.
> 2. She can give two chocolates to every colleague other than chosen one.
> 3. She can give five chocolates to every colleague other than chosen one.
>
> Calculate minimum number of such operations needed to ensure that
>   every colleague has the same number of chocolates.

My code is like below I will appreciate your advice to improve performance.

```
object EqualsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val numOfTestCases = readInt();
    Range(0, numOfTestCases).foreach(i => {
      val numberCount = readInt();
      var numbers = Array.ofDim[Int](numberCount)
      val inputNumbers = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split("""\s+""")
      0.until(numberCount).foreach(i => {
        numbers(i) = inputNumbers(i).trim.toInt
      })
      // val numbers = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(s => s.toInt);
      var baseLine = numbers.min
      println(calOpCount(numbers, baseLine))
    })

    def f(b: Int)(s: Int): Int = {
      val i = s - b
      if (i==0) 0
      else if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5) 1
      else (i/5 + (i%5)/2 + ((i%5)%2))
    }

    def calOpCount(source: Array[Int], baseLine: Int): Int = {
       val baseLines = 0.to(baseLine)
       val result = for {i <- baseLines; f1 = f(i)(_)} yield (source.map(s => f1(s.toInt)).sum)
       result.min
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The performance issue and the bug

The program essentially looks for the minimum operations to reduce the numbers to *some base line*.
There are two problems with the choice of base lines.

The performance issue is that you try base lines from 0 until the minimum value.
Consider this input:

```
999
```

The program will check base lines from 0 to 999, in vain.
You need up check only the 3 baselines: `min`, `min - 1` and `min - 2`.

The second problem is a bug, and it is a related issue.
Consider this input:

```
0 4 4
```

The program will check only one base line, 0.
And that will give the incorrect result 4.
Checking -1 would give the correct result 3.

#### Working with user input

The `readInt` method is deprecated in favor of `StdIn.readInt`.

The way you parsed the input is unnecessarily complicated.
This line is commented out,
even though it was really on the right track:

> ```
> val numbers = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(s => s.toInt);
> ```

#### Scala style

Some of the `var` could have been `val` or unnecessary altogether,
and semicolons at end of lines are not recommended.
Also, you used `Range(0, numOfTestCases)` at one point,
even though you used the more idiomatic `x.until(y)` syntax elsewhere.

#### Alternative implementation

Putting the above tips together:

```
import scala.io.StdIn

object Solution {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val numOfTestCases = StdIn.readInt()
    0.until(numOfTestCases).foreach(_ => {
      StdIn.readInt()
      val numbers = StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(s => s.toInt)
      println(calOpCount(numbers))
    })
  }

  def steps(i: Int): Int = {
    if (i == 0) 0
    else if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5) 1
    else i / 5 + (i % 5) / 2 + ((i % 5) % 2)
  }

  def calOpCount(source: Array[Int]): Int = {
    val min = source.min
    (for {base <- 0.to(2)} yield source.map(s => steps(s - min + base)).sum).min
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you kind and detail comments. I figured out what was the problem.